# luabridge class object inside class

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

weird problem I have a program that uses multiple classes some of these classes are used to define objects inside of other class but I can't modify their values not sure if that made sense but I'll try and demonstrate

C++ file

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
        c = 0
    }
    int c;
};

class B{
public:
    A d;
};

luabridge::getNamespace(L)
    .addNamespace("test")
        .addClass<A>("A")
            .addConstructor<void(*) ()>()
            .addData("c", &A::c)
        .endClass()
        .addClass<B>("B")
            .addConstructor<void(*) ()>()
            .addData("d", &A::d)
        .endClass()
    .endNamespace();
```

now in the lua file we have

```
var = test.B()
var.d.c = 2
print(var.d.c)
```

and the program prints

```
0
```

just to clarify if A's constructor sets c to 666 then the program outputs 666

Comment: Why would `B.d.c = 2` be expected to work?  I don't see any static members in any of the classes.

Comment: How are static members going to make any difference at all?  Everything is running in C++ it's only when I try the same thing in lua I have a problem.

Comment: Can you include the other "crap" that you omitted in the luabridge initialization?

Comment: Yeah just give me a second

Comment: @TimCooper by static you meant literally to just go static int c;

Comment: The issue is that you are doing `B.d.c = 2`, not `var.d.c`.  `var` should be an instance of `B`, in this case.

Comment: @TimCooper sorry that was just a typo in the stackoverflow post not in my actual code... I should learn to double check my posts so they make sense and work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object declared as `Type variableName` is passed to Lua by value, as a copy managed by Lua. Hence `var.d` returns a copy of that `d` object, and with `var.d.c` you are modifying the `c` variable of that copy, not the `c` variable of the original `d` object.

An object declared as `Type* variableName` is passed by reference, hence you modify the original `d` object, that's why your second approach works.

More info in the [LuaBridge manual](http://vinniefalco.com/LuaBridge/Manual#s3).

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was make the object of class A inside class B a pointer and I'm not sure why... I just found it out along the debug road after about 2 days

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
        c = 0
    }
    int c;
};

class B{
public:
    A* d;
};

luabridge::getNamespace(L)
    .addNamespace("test")
        .addClass<A>("A")
            .addConstructor<void(*) ()>()
            .addData("c", &A::c)
        .endClass()
        .addClass<B>("B")
            .addConstructor<void(*) ()>()
            .addData("d", &A::d)
        .endClass()
    .endNamespace();
```

Comment: If someone could explain why this fixed it that would be greatly appreciated